# Flutter & Firebase: Compression before upload image

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-storage, flutter

I want to send photo selected by user in my app to Firebase Storage. I have a simple class with property `_imageFile` which is set like this:

```
File _imageFile;

_getImage() async {
    var fileName = await ImagePicker.pickImage();
    setState(() {
        _imageFile = fileName;
    });
}
```

after that I send photo like with this code:

```
final String rand1 = "${new Random().nextInt(10000)}";
final String rand2 = "${new Random().nextInt(10000)}";
final String rand3 = "${new Random().nextInt(10000)}";
final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('${rand1}_${rand2}_${rand3}.jpg');
final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.put(_imageFile);
final Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;
print(downloadUrl);
```

The problem is that the photos are often very large. Is there any method in Flutter/Dart to compress and resize photo before upload? I am ok with loss of quality.

Comment: You might want to give https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image a try, I have not tried this, but when you read the documentation you will find that you can encode images into different formats and specify different compression levels.

Comment: You might want to check https://pub.dev/packages/uuid for uploading files on firebase because using random numbers may have collisions at some time.

Comment: If you are in for lutter web check out my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60728872/flutter-web-how-do-you-compress-an-image-file/68358346#68358346

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [image_picker](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/image_picker) plugin is currently very simple. It would be straightforward to add an option for specifying the desired size/quality of the picked image. If you do this, please send us a pull request!

Comment: What parameter to pass in the image picker library? Can you provide the link for it

Comment: I did not find any params to resize all images above X and Y, did you found it? Thanks

Comment: use  an imageQuality parameter  in the image picker library.

Comment: SYNTAX: ImagePicker.pickImage(source.ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 85); But this will compress the image by 85% of its current quality, so if an image is already of less quality then it will just mess it up even more!




ALTERNATE SOLUTION: ImagePicker.pickImage(source.ImageSource.gallery, maxHeight: 200); Using maxHeight will only compress the image if it greater than mentioned height!

Comment: Is there any solution for the web?

Answer (score 83):

### **June 05, 2020 - Update**

The [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) plugin now supports an `imageQuality` paramater. You can do something like

```
ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
PickedFile compressedImage = await imagePicker.getImage(
  source: ImageSource.camera,
  imageQuality: 85,
);
```

### **Old Answer**

#### or if you want to compress an image **without** using `ImagePicker`

I ran into this and was able to accomplish compression / resizing with the Dart [image package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image) along with [path provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider). You can look at dart [image api](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/image/1.1.22/image/image-library.html) and [examples](https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/wiki/Examples) for other ways and more help.

Here's what I did:

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as Im;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:math' as Math;

void compressImage() async {
  File imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage();
  final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final path = tempDir.path;
  int rand = new Math.Random().nextInt(10000);

  Im.Image image = Im.decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
  Im.Image smallerImage = Im.copyResize(image, 500); // choose the size here, it will maintain aspect ratio
  
  var compressedImage = new File('$path/img_$rand.jpg')..writeAsBytesSync(Im.encodeJpg(image, quality: 85));
}
```

Then I uploaded `compressedImage` to firebase storage. You can adjust the quality that the jpg is saved with using the quality property, in my case I chose 85 (out of 100).

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I Am Also doing the same stuff but it takes long time in iOS (if the image is take from it)

Comment: yes it's quite long and I cannot undersand why it freeze my UI even though the code is async

Comment: i have found that it does freeze my ui for a while in debug, it runs much better when the app is built for release

Comment: @gbaccetta being async doesn't mean its parallel

Comment: @gbaccetta it also doesn't mean multi threading, it all depends on the developers on how they implement their async functionality

Comment: @gbaccetta dart is single threaded. So it all runs on the UI thread. To achieve true multi threading, use an isolate.

Comment: @Mans What is average image file size reduction?

Comment: Why is the smallerImage not used?

Comment: but image picker doesn't support png compression what to do  in that case

Comment: @mans my question is do I need to ask for permission in android for this code(like storage permission or something)

Answer (score 8):

**There are many solutions :**

### Use **[image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)** package:

You can use the built-in `imageQuality` property of **ImagePicker** to compress the image. This property takes a value between `0` and `100` and represents a percentage of the quality of the original image.

First, add `image_picker` as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml file.

**Usage**

```
  File _image;

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,  
                imageQuality: 25,
    );

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }
```

> **The advantage of this approach** is that it is embedded in the
> image_picker package and is therefore incredibly easy to use.

### You can also adjust the quality from the Image widget.

Use `filterQuality`  to set the `FilterQuality` of the image.

**Example :**

```
Image.asset('assets/kab1.png', filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,),
```

These properties are present in `AssetImage` , `NetworkImage` , `FileImage` and `MemoryImage`.

> **You can also simply resize the image (Resizing an image can compress it). To do so, try the [ResizeImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ResizeImage-class.html) widget**
>
> **Another solution is to use [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress) package**

Answer (score 7):

Use [image_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker#-readme-tab-) plugin and call pick image function as

`Future<File> imageFile = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery  , maxHeight:  200 , maxWidth: 200 );`

change maxHeight and maxWidth to whatever size of image you need.

Comment: This worked for me! I used 400 instead of 200 to get a better quality. Generally, a 200x200 is less than 20kb, and the 400x400 is less than 40kb

Comment: Great, this is something I needed. i don't want to use another library for compress.

Comment: 2020 : 'pickImage' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use imagePicker.getImage() method instead..

Answer (score 4):

Besides mentioning this **native** library:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_image_compress

This is a fully **dart based compressor with isolates**, which might make the compression parallel to UI thread in multi core CPUs.

> You might want to use compute function which makes using isolates simpler:
>   https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/compute.html
>   https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/background-parsing/

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as ImageLib;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<void> getCompressedImage(SendPort sendPort) async {
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();

  sendPort.send(receivePort.sendPort);
  List msg = (await receivePort.first) as List;

  String srcPath = msg[0];
  String name = msg[1];
  String destDirPath = msg[2];
  SendPort replyPort = msg[3];

  ImageLib.Image image =
      ImageLib.decodeImage(await new File(srcPath).readAsBytes());

  if (image.width > 500 || image.height > 500) {
    image = ImageLib.copyResize(image, 500);
  }

  File destFile = new File(destDirPath + '/' + name);
  await destFile.writeAsBytes(ImageLib.encodeJpg(image, quality: 60));

  replyPort.send(destFile.path);
}

Future<File> compressImage(File f) async {
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();

  await Isolate.spawn(getCompressedImage, receivePort.sendPort);
  SendPort sendPort = await receivePort.first;

  ReceivePort receivePort2 = ReceivePort();

  sendPort.send([
    f.path,
    f.uri.pathSegments.last,
    (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
    receivePort2.sendPort,
  ]);

  var msg = await receivePort2.first;

  return new File(msg);
}
```

---

```
if (false ==
    await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(
        Permission.ReadExternalStorage)) {
  await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(
    Permission.ReadExternalStorage);
}

File img = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery);
if (null != img) {
  img = await compressImage(img);
}
```

Comment: Hangs up sometimes :( Without exception

Comment: Forgot to `import 'dart:isolate';`

Answer (score 2):

The following code is what I use to take an image with the camera and then compress it:

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'dart:io' show File;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show compute;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' show BuildContext;
import 'package:image/image.dart' as Im;
import 'dart:math' as Math;
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' show getTemporaryDirectory;

Future<File> takeCompressedPicture(BuildContext context) async {
  var _imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  if (_imageFile == null) {
    return null;
  }

  // You can have a loading dialog here but don't forget to pop before return file;

  final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final rand = Math.Random().nextInt(10000);
  _CompressObject compressObject =
      _CompressObject(_imageFile, tempDir.path, rand);
  String filePath = await _compressImage(compressObject);
  print('new path: ' + filePath);
  File file = File(filePath);

  // Pop loading

  return file;
}

Future<String> _compressImage(_CompressObject object) async {
  return compute(_decodeImage, object);
}

String _decodeImage(_CompressObject object) {
  Im.Image image = Im.decodeImage(object.imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
  Im.Image smallerImage = Im.copyResize(
      image, 1024); // choose the size here, it will maintain aspect ratio
  var decodedImageFile = File(object.path + '/img_${object.rand}.jpg');
  decodedImageFile.writeAsBytesSync(Im.encodeJpg(smallerImage, quality: 85));
  return decodedImageFile.path;
}

class _CompressObject {
  File imageFile;
  String path;
  int rand;

  _CompressObject(this.imageFile, this.path, this.rand);
}
```

You can call this very easy with this:

```
import 'path/to/compress_image.dart' as CompressImage;
// ...
File file = await CompressImage.takeCompressedPicture(context);
```

Comment: gives this error for   `return compute(_decodeImage, object);` like this 'Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a closure - Function '_decodeImage@38216194':.)'

Answer (score 0):

While i am using

> package:image/image.dart

facing below issues

- showing blank page while converting image ( may be taking so much process while compressing image)
- After compression image was stretched and not looking good

Then used below plugin, same working fine without any issue, even faster and what i expected

```
https://github.com/btastic/flutter_native_image.git
```

steps and method available in above link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin called [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress)

```
// Active image file
File _imageFile;

// Select an image via gallery or camera
Future<void> _pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
  File selected = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);

// Compress plugin
  File compressedImage = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
    selected.path,
    selected.path,
    quality: 50,
  );

  setState(() {
    _imageFile = compressedImage;
    print('compressedimagesize: ${_imageFile.lengthSync()}');
  });
}
```

Voila! Compressed file image

Comment: its going to say that the target path cannot be the same as the file path.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Firebase, one option would be using the Extension - Resize Image. It gives you the option to keep or delete the original image and it is very easy to install and use.

Comment: From Review: This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows,

```
//Compressing Image
    File compressedImg = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(
      _image.path,
      quality: 70,
    );
//Compressing Image
```

Answer (score 0):

Well
**1. If you are in mobile you could use** `flutter_image_compress: ^1.0.0`  will do the work

Eg.
Pass youe Uint8List and quality, you will get compressed image in no time.

```
Future<Uint8List> testComporessList(Uint8List uint8List) async {
    var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithList(
      uint8List,
      quality: 50,
    );
    return result;
}
```

**2. But If you are in flutter web then you won't get any other option than image picker etc etc.**
I end up using javascript. You can find answer here.
[Flutter Web: How Do You Compress an Image/File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60728872/flutter-web-how-do-you-compress-an-image-file/68358346#68358346)

Answer (score 0):

ImagePicker has now a default option to reduce imageQuality.

```
 final returnedImage = await ImagePicker()
    .pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50);
```

Here

> imageQuality: 50

means that the image will be reduced to 50% of it's actual quality.

Answer (score -1):

**Update 2020 'pickImage' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use imagePicker.getImage() method instead****

```
  ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
   PickedFile compressedImage = await imagePicker.getImage(
  source: ImageSource.camera,
  imageQuality: 80,
);
```

Doc for ImageQuality :

> Returns a PickedFile object wrapping the image that was picked. The
> returned PickedFile is intended to be used within a single APP
> session. Do not save the file path and use it across sessions. The
> source argument controls where the image comes from. This can be
> either ImageSource.camera or ImageSource.gallery. Where iOS supports
> HEIC images, Android 8 and below doesn't. Android 9 and above only
> support HEIC images if used in addition to a size modification, of
> which the usage is explained below. If specified, the image will be at
> most maxWidth wide and maxHeight tall. Otherwise the image will be
> returned at it's original width and height. The imageQuality argument
> modifies the quality of the image, ranging from 0-100 where 100 is the
> original/max quality. If imageQuality is null, the image with the
> original quality will be returned. Compression is only supported for
> certain image types such as JPEG and on Android PNG and WebP, too. If
> compression is not supported for the image that is picked, a warning
> message will be logged. Use preferredCameraDevice to specify the
> camera to use when the source is ImageSource.camera. The
> preferredCameraDevice is ignored when source is ImageSource.gallery.
> It is also ignored if the chosen camera is not supported on the
> device. Defaults to CameraDevice.rear. Note that Android has no
> documented parameter for an intent to specify if the front or rear
> camera should be opened, this function is not guaranteed to work on an
> Android device. In Android, the MainActivity can be destroyed for
> various reasons. If that happens, the result will be lost in this
> call. You can then call getLostData when your app relaunches to
> retrieve the lost data.