# Flutter Image Compression

Tags: image, dart, flutter, compression, image-compression

I wanted to do some image compression before uploading to my Firestore and ran into following thread: [Flutter & Firebase: Compression before upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515679/flutter-firebase-compression-before-upload-image)

The uploading works totally fine, but I cannot recognize any compression regarding the file size... Even if I decrease the quality from 85 to 1, the file still has the same size. Same thing if I upload the image without calling the compression method at all. Here is the code snippet:

```
void compressImage() async {
    print('starting compression');
    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path = tempDir.path;
    int rand = new Math.Random().nextInt(10000);

    Im.Image image = Im.decodeImage(file.readAsBytesSync());
    Im.copyResize(image, 500);

//    image.format = Im.Image.RGBA;
//    Im.Image newim = Im.remapColors(image, alpha: Im.LUMINANCE);

    Im.Image smallerImage = Im.copyResize(image, 500); // choose the size here, it will maintain aspect ratio


    var newim2 = new File('$path/img_$rand.jpg')
      ..writeAsBytesSync(Im.encodeJpg(smallerImage, quality: 85));

    setState(() {
      file = newim2;
    });
    print('done');
  }
```

Any idea what I have to change, to make the compression working?

Best regards!

Answer (score 3):

you can use below plugin, same working fine without any issue, even faster and what i expected

https://github.com/btastic/flutter_native_image.git

steps and method available in above link.